# Different analytics for website and app with webview

Tags: webview, google-analytics, web-analytics

I don't have a lot of experience with Google Analytics so sorry if it's an easy question.

At the moment, I have a website with Google Analytics. I am planning to do an app that will contain a webview with this website. Is there a way I can differentiate the analytics coming from the app and the ones coming from the website?

We now have some tracking coming from webviews but this is when someone opens the link of our website in other apps (like Mail, Twitter...).

I basically need a specific tracking for our specific app.

Thank you for your help!